# Merge Identity and app contact and migrations into one database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, dbcontext

I have posed a couple of questions on here around publishing multiple DB context and migrations due to VS2013 creating the ApplicationDbContext for IdentitiesModel and my own AppContext for my database which was imported using Code First on an Existing database. I have got this working locally but when I publish the app only the Identities database is being created no matter what I try.

While continuing to look for the solution I had a thought of maybe merging the Identities Database into my App Database so only having one Context to deal with.

Do you think this is a possible workaround and if so how would you go about doing it?

Cheers,
Kevin.

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated as I have hit a brick wall here and being new to asp and mvc I'm not sure where to turn. Cheers Kevin.